# How to get correct Date after conversion from milliseconds to days?

Tags: java, date

I have a Date String in the format `yyyy-MM-dd` which I parse to Date object. After parsing I get the correct Date. I need to convert the Date timestamp from milliseconds to days and then pass the number of days to some function in which I need to get the first correct Date from the number of days.

The problem I am having is when I convert number of days back to milliseconds and create a Date object from those milliseconds I get the incorrect Date.

Example of the problem:

For date string `2019-08-19` 
I get parsed Date `Mon Aug 19 00:00:00 GMT+02:00 2019`.
I then convert this timestamp to days like this `TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(date.time)` and get `18126`.
After converting back to milliseconds using `TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(numOfDays)` and using that value to create a new Date object like `Date(TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(numOfDays))` i get the value of Date `Sun Aug 18 02:00:00 GMT+02:00 2019`.

Is there some way that I can get the correct Date from number of days?

Comment: By `Date` do you mean `java.util.Date`? Please stop using that awful API. Use `LocalDate` instead.

Comment: Yes, `java.util.Date`. I am usually using `java.util.Calendar` for other date related stuff. I will check out `LocalDate`, do you believe that `LocalDate` can solve my problem?

Comment: `LocalDate`, `OffsetDate` or `ZonedDate` may solve the problem. There is also `Instant` in `java.time` and that is the API to be used nowadays, so get into it.

Comment: "do you believe that LocalDate can solve my problem" - well, maybe not `LocalDate` itself but the entire new jave.time api which provides a lot of functionality to extract the data you need.

Comment: "and then pass the number of days to some function in which I need to get the first correct Date from the number of days." <-- What does this function do exactly?

Comment: Also please note that your problem seems to be related to timezone differences (i.e. at at least one point you're not using the correct timezone). That might still be a problem with the java.time api so we'd need to see some code of what you're doing. So please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @Thomas OP doesn't seem to care about timezones all that much, which is why I suggested `LocalDate`, so that OP doesn't have to worry about timezones.

Comment: I am using `MPChart` library for `Android`, and for `xAxis` I need to pass some kind of `float` value which I can later convert to `Date` in the `ValueFormatter` for labels of the `xAxis`. Because I am displaying days (Mon, Tue... in one instance, or 1., 2.... in other instance) on the `xAxis` and need the `x` values to be appart from each other by `1` i thought that converting from milliseconds to days would do the trick. @Sweeper So the function i mentioned is actually the label formatter in which I convert back to Date and format the labels.

Comment: @Sweeper You are correct, i do not need the timezone differences I just need the first correct date so that I can format the labels correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### java.time

It’s pretty simple when you know how:

```
    String dateString = "2019-08-19";
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(dateString);
    long days = date.getLong(ChronoField.EPOCH_DAY);
    System.out.println("Days since epoch: " + days);
```

Output:

> Days since epoch: 18127

Converting back:

```
    LocalDate convertedBack = LocalDate.ofEpochDay(days);
    System.out.println("Converted back to a date: " + convertedBack);
```

> Converted back to a date: 2019-08-19

**Link:** [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.